# how to 'move' a list

Tags: lists, itemize

In the first picture is the current itemize list that I have and in the second picture is the itemize list that I WANT to have

### What I have:

[image: what i have]

### What I want:

[image: what i want]

Comment: `\usepackage{enumitem}` and `\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=...]` with appropriate values for `...`

Comment: If you do not want the bullet to go into the margin, the simplest is `\begin{itemize}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*]`.